# sql server error- cannot connect to server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I had been using SQL server 2005 without any problem but now when i opened it and tried to connect it am getting this error---

TITLE: Connect to Server

---

Cannot connect to POONAM-C586A95C\SQLEXPRESS.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
   connection   to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify 
   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow 
   remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error 
   Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Why am I getting this error and how can I remove it?

Comment: Expand on "but now when i opened it and tried to connect". Do you mean from SQL Server Management studio or your application?

Comment: First i tried connecting through an application on visual web developer and got the same error. then i tried connecting directly from sql server 2005 server management studio and got the same error yet again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check SQL Server is running on the
   target machine. - If not start the Services using Services.msc
2. Check whether you have proper access
   rights to connect to the machine. - If not contact you system admin for access rights.
3. Check the server allows remote
   connections. - You can enable it by Right clicking on the server node and check for the specific settings.

UPDATE:

Check this link : [SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: )](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: Its on the same machine from which I am connecting it. It was working perfectly fine. Its just now that its suddenly giving this error.

Comment: Please check the authentication settings. Try to connect with Windows.

Comment: I connect with windows authentication only.

Comment: Even I checked it out. It says...1) SQL Server should be up and running. Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”. I checked it and state of sql server and sql server browser is stopped. What should I do to bring it to running state?

Comment: I even added sqlservr exe file to the exceptions in the firewall but i dont think that could hav been a problem b'coz it was working perfectly without any changes in the firewall setting.

Comment: I don't think SQL Browser is required.

Comment: Aint there any way to resolve this problem? Will I have to install sqlserver again? And will i lose all my databases? I had repaired my windows, can that be any reason for this problem?

Comment: Just try osql -E command with -S POONAM-C586A95C\SQLEXPRESS, in the command prompt. It will try to connect using Windows Authentication. If it fails some problem with SQL, try re-install.

Comment: I tried it. It gives error and suggests that it might be coz of settings not allowing remote connections. I changed the settings to allow remote connections and when i try to start the mssqlserver service its shows "an error occurred while performing this operation".

Comment: Seems like problem with SQL. Try re-install / repair

Comment: I think the problem is with the OS files. A part from the error log file says..."2011-05-17 16:21:50.04 spid4s      Starting up database 'master'.
2011-05-17 16:21:50.04 spid4s      Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2011-05-17 16:21:50.04 spid4s      FCB::Open: Operating system error 5(Access is denied.) occurred while creating or opening file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation."

Comment: Which OS you are using? Win 7? Try Run As Administrator option for SQL Management Studio.

Comment: its windows xp professional sp2. A few days back i was having problem with my pc. It used to go off after 5-7 mins so i had repaired it. And since then I have been a victim of this sqlserver error.

Comment: Sorry I am not faced this issue :( Seems like some security issue.

Comment: And I am logged in as administrator only.

Comment: @anuraj thanks for ur efforts. @all: 31 views and only 2 people to post something....i am diappointed:(

Answer (score 0):

*> Even I checked it out. It says...1) SQL Server should be up and running. Go to All Programs >> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 >> Configuration Tools >> SQL Server Configuration Manager >> SQL Server Services, and check if SQL Server service status is “Running”. I checked it and state of sql server and sql server browser is stopped. What should I do to bring it to running state? –*

Right click the services and select `Start` to start them. If they don't start, run `Event Viewer` to see what causes the error.

If they start up and you still can't connect, try using the address `.\SQLEXPRESS` - if this works, your computer name might have changed, check this by looking at the properties of `My Computer`

Comment: I had to reinstall SQL Server. Problem got solved after that only. Thanks for your concern.:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went to SQL configuration manager. Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 -> SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Then I checked SQL Services. Find your data base instance and start the service. While I'm there, I also clicked on the SQL Server Agent to ensure TCP is enabled for the database instance as well. This fixed all connection issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your services are running and still facing this error then Just Check the Trust server Certificate Checkbox, which is present above connect button, this works for me.